# QProgressDialog not showing text label

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to show a window with a message while some stuff are processing in my Qt application, so I have decided to use `QProgressDialog`.

But I have a problem, the text label is not showing: 
 [QProgressDialog not showing the text label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxtgb.png)

My code:

```
QProgressDialog progressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setWindowTitle("Cargando");
progressDialog.setLabelText("Cargando los datos del volumen, por favor espere");
progressDialog.setCancelButton(0);
progressDialog.show();

// DOING SOME STUFF

progressDialog.close();
```

I realize that, If I use `progressDialog.exec()` instead of `progressDialog.show()`, the text label appears but the application gets blocked.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your dialog isn't showing anything is probably because of your `DOING SOME STUFF. If you are doing this stuff on the main thread, it will block your UI -and the dialog from drawing it's contents.

Depending on what this stuff is, you have 2 options:

If you are doing something in a loop, just call `QApplication::processEvents` on every iteration.

If the operations themselve take longer or it's not a loop, you will have to execute this stuff asynchronously, on a different thread. For example, by using `QtConcurrent::run`. Use a `QFutureWatcher` to close the dialog once the concurrent operation finished